# Accessing base class member in a multiple level composite relationship

Tags: c++, vector, composition

I have three level composite type relationship between classes, with the member being a vector. Below is the code:

```
class vec1{
  public: int x;
  vec1(int n):x(n){}
};
class vec2{
  public: std::vector<vec1> v1;
};
class vec3{
  public: std::vector<vec2> v2;
};
```

In main() function I will create an object

```
 vec1 v(10);
 vec3 v3;
```

I want to access class **"vec1's x variable" using v3 object**

Which v3 object vector functions can be used to print "vec1's x variable"-->

Comment: None. `vec3` stores `vec2`'s, not `vec1`'s.

Comment: @NathanOliver, you are correct, but my problem wants to access vec1's variable from vec3. The elements all are public here.

Comment: The question is which `v2`'s `v1`s are you trying to access?

Comment: `v3.v2[0].v1[0].x` but it is not possible as `v3.v2` is empty

Comment: `vec3` doesn't inherit `vec1` or has any other relationship to it, so how would you expect to be able to access a member of `vec1` via a `vec3`?? Your question doesn't make sense. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Don't confuse instances and classes. Just because a class (`vec3`) has a data member based on another class (`vec2`) doesn't mean that _every_ instance of `vec3` knows about every instance of `vec2` (or `vec1`). Your `v3` doesn't know `v` exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access class **"vec1's x variable" using v3 object**

That shows lack of clarity on your part as to how the different objects are related.

`v3` holds a `std::vector` of `vec2` objects. That is an empty `std::vector` when `v3` is constructed the way you have. You have to add an object of type `vec2` to `v3.v2` to be able to access any `vec2` object from `v3`.

```
v3.v2.push_back(vec2());
vec2& v2 = v3.v2[0]; // Now you have access to a vec2 object from v3.
```

However, the `vec2` object's `v1` is an empty `std::vector`. You need to add a `vec1` object to it before you can access such an object from `v3`.

```
v3.v2.push_back(vec2);
v3.v2[0].v1.push_back(vec1(10));
vec1& v1 = v3.v2[0].v1[0]; // Now you have access to a vec1 object from v3.
```

Now, you can access and modify the `x` of the `vec1` object.

```
v3.v2.push_back(vec2);
v3.v2[0].v1.push_back(vec1(10));

// Get the value and print it to cout.
std::cout << v3.v2[0].v1[0].x << std::endl;

Change the value
v3.v2[0].v1[0].x = 20;
```